# What would cause a form's 'insert into' code to only save to the database 80% of the time?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-insert

This shelter's website I've recently taken over has a form that inserts into a database. But it's been reported that it is only saving some of the submissions, not all, to the database. I can't find anything consistent between the submissions that have failed (the visitors emailed their info in).

Things I've tried and other notes:

1. I thought it might be a char limit on a column but I confirmed they're all TEXT types and max submission was 3 sentences.
2. I checked for reserved words and didn't see any being used
3. Form does sometimes save just fine. Estimate about 1 in 5 fail.
4. I went thru all other posts on this site noting this error but none of the accepted solutions fixed the problem for me
5. I can recreate the error every time I try to resubmit one of the submissions that failed but I can also submit my own with test values and it saves to the database just fine.
6. I researched the possibility of a column rejecting a special character like an apostrophe but came up with nothing solid. There is nothing unique about the data being submitted outside of a couple fields being 3 sentences long.
7. The form submits to a php file with the code noted below. It's not on the form page itself.

This is the error that comes up when it does fail:
Error adding application: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Here's my code:

```html
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'oursite_main', 'password');
if (!$link)
{
  die('Could not connect to database:' .mysql_error());
}


if (!mysqli_select_db($link, 'oursite_application'))
{
  $output = 'unable to locate the application database.';
  include 'output.html.php';
  exit();
}

$age = implode(', ',$_POST['age']);
  
$sql = "INSERT INTO adoption (name,address,city,phone,email,dog,sex,age,details,setting,home,permission,wkhours,time,family,pets,livestock,ydsize,fencing,livingqtrs,vet,activities,experience,whybc,greatdog, lookingfor,shelter,ifyes,helpfulinfo,status,year) VALUES('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[address]' , '$_POST[city]' , '$_POST[phone]' , '$_POST[email]'  ,'$_POST[dog]' , '$_POST[sex]' , '$age' , '$_POST[details]' , '$_POST[setting]' , '$_POST[home]' , '$_POST[permission]' , '$_POST[wkhours]' , '$_POST[time]' , '$_POST[family]' , '$_POST[pets]' , '$_POST[livestock]' , '$_POST[ydsize]' , '$_POST[fencing]' , '$_POST[livingqtrs]' , '$_POST[vet]' , '$_POST[activities]' , '$_POST[experience]' , '$_POST[whybc]' , '$_POST[greatdog]' , '$_POST[lookingfor]' , '$_POST[shelter]' , '$_POST[ifyes]' , '$_POST[helpfulinfo]' , '$_POST[status]', '$_POST[year]')";
```

Comment: that sql is vulnerable to sql injection and it is likely that punctuation characters are causing errors. Use prepared statements instead and I'd be tempted to bet the omissions disappear

Comment: SQL Injections would. This code is as dangerous as possible. Fix this and you solve two problems at once.